# How to fix failed to fetch error thrown by fetch() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a separate basic nodejs server on localhost and a separate frontend.

When I try to fetch while the server is offline, `fetch()` throws **failed to fetch*** error. So for that, I tried to handle or catch that error by checking the response. ok like

```
if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText)
```

Although it catches an error still it throws the error. Even I tried to console logging it.

```
if (!response.ok) return console.log(response.statusText)
```

Here are interfaces.

```
export interface 
CommunicatorParameter {
  endUrl: string;
}

interface ErrorResponse {
  message: string;
}

interface V01List {
  tittle: string;
  url: string;
}

type V01ListData = Array<V01List>;
type ReleasedVersionsResponse = Array<string>;
type CurrentVersionResponse = string;

interface SuccessResponse{
  data: V01ListData | ReleasedVersionsResponse | CurrentVersionResponse ;
}

export type ServerResponse = SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse;
export type CommunicatorResponse = SuccessResponse['data'];
```

Below is the service function which helps to communicate with the server. Also, I want this function should return direct data(key) value.

```
interface SuccessResponse{
  data: V01ListData | ReleasedVersionsResponse | CurrentVersionResponse ;
}
```

```
// fetchDataFromServer.ts

// these are type and interfaces.
import { CommunicatorParameter, ServerResponse, CommunicatorResponse } from "./declarations/index.js";

// These are helper functions
import { buildValidURL, checkForBadResponse } from "./helpers/index.js";

export async function fetchDataFromServer({ endUrl }: CommunicatorParameter): Promise<CommunicatorResponse> {
  const fullURL = buildValidURL(endUrl);
  
  const response = await fetch(fullURL, {
    method: 'GET'
  });
  console.log(response.headers)
  const jsonParsedData = <ServerResponse>await response.json();
  
//This function simply checks response and throws an error if the response is not ok.
  checkForBadResponse(response, jsonParsedData);
  
// Here I am doing this because if I return from try/catch or if statement the return type of function does not match and typescript complain about that. I don't think it is a good way to do it. But don't know how to do it.

  return ('data' in jsonParsedData) ? jsonParsedData.data : [];
}
```

I have another function that will help to fetch version data from the server which uses the above communicator fun.

```
// fetchCurrentVersion.ts

import { fetchDataFromServer } from "../services/fetchDataFromServer.js";

export async function fetchCurrentListVersion() {
  const END_URL = "/current_version";
  
  try {
    const response = await fetchDataFromServer({ endUrl: END_URL });

// Here I am checking the type of response/data which is returned by communicator as my need, see the interface SuccessResponse data key.

    if (typeof response === 'string') {
      return response;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
  // fallback return value;
  return "v0.0";
}
```

Is this approach good? I felt like still there is a better way of doing this. If you could help, please

Comment: I don't see how `if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText)` **catches** an error?!

Comment: Notice you might want to check for bad responses *before* calling `response.json()`. Or are you certain that all your 400 and 500 error messages (and also those of any HTTP middlewares) are formatted as JSON?

Comment: "*When i try to fetch while server is offline, `fetch()` throws "failed to fetch" error.*" - yes, the `fetch()` promise itself rejects, it doesn't even return a bad response when there is none.

Comment: So there is no way to handle this?

Comment: Sure there is, you already do it: with `try`/`catch` around the `await fetch()`.